# Spring Data JPA in SpringBoot 2.1.4.RELEASE Does not delete

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this method defined on a service

```
@Transactional
public void delete(Shop shop) {

    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("deleting Shop1 [ " + shop + " ]");
    }       

    shop.getPurchases().stream()
            .forEach(p -> purchaseService.delete(p));

    shop.getPurchases().clear();

    if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
        LOG.debug("deleting Shop2 [ " + shop + " ]");
    }

    shopRepository.delete(shop);

}
```

I also have this properties defined:

```
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.format_sql=true
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
```

But when I run the method to delete some shops I don't see any delete sentences in the console and the shops are not deleted

Comment: you're quite specific about referring to Spring Boot 2.1.4... have you tried with another version of spring boot? say Spring Boot 1.x?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide your repository class and your purchaseService object information. if you are clearing the list than why are you deleting before it? Please provide more information on the same to assist you.